# How to create a transformed Doctrine 2 entity that is based on several unique keys

Tags: mysql, orm, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I try to implement the following in scenario in Doctrine 2:

- There are drivers that drive vehicles in races
- In these races, the vehicles can have an accident

This looks like the following in Skipper:

[image]

With the export to Doctrine 2 annotation based entities, this looks like this (Getter and setters were snipped):

**Driver.php**

```
<?php
namespace Racing\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Driver
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="bigint")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $Id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=false)
     */
    private $Name;
}
```

**Vehicle.php**

```
<?php
namespace Racing\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Vehicle
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="bigint")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $Id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=false)
     */
    private $Name;
}
```

**Race.php**

```
<?php
namespace Racing\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Race
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $Id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=false)
     */
    private $Name;
}
```

**Accident.php**

```
<?php
namespace Racing\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Accident
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=false)
     */
    private $Description;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Racing\Entity\RacingVehicle")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="Racing_Vehicle_Driver_Id", referencedColumnName="Driver_Id", nullable=false),
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="Racing_Vehicle_Vehicle_Id", referencedColumnName="Vehicle_Id", nullable=false)
     * })
     */
    private $RacingVehicle;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Racing\Entity\Race")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="Race_Id", referencedColumnName="Id", nullable=false)
     */
    private $Race;
}
```

**RacingVehicle.php**

```
<?php
namespace Racing\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class RacingVehicle
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $Startnumber;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Racing\Entity\Driver")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="Driver_Id", referencedColumnName="Id", nullable=false)
     */
    private $Driver;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Racing\Entity\Vehicle")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="Vehicle_Id", referencedColumnName="Id", nullable=false)
     */
    private $Vehicle;
}
```

A test sample looks like this:

```
// Get the entity manager
$sservicelocator = $this->getServiceLocator();
$entitymanager = $sservicelocator->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default');

// Create a driver
$driver = new Driver();
$driver->setName("Michael Schumacher");
$entitymanager->persist($driver);

// Create a vehicle
$vehicle = new Vehicle();
$vehicle->setName("Ferrari");
$entitymanager->persist($vehicle);

// Create a race
$race = new Race();
$race->setName("Monaco");
$entitymanager->persist($race);

// Create a racing vehicle
$racingvehicle = new RacingVehicle();
$racingvehicle->setDriver($driver);
$racingvehicle->setVehicle($vehicle);
$racingvehicle->setStartnumber(42);
$entitymanager->persist($racingvehicle);

// Create an accident
$accident = new Accident();
$accident->setRace($race);
$accident->setRacingVehicle($racingvehicle);
$entitymanager->persist($accident); // <-------------- Error line

// Flush
$entitymanager->flush();
```

As soon I try to persist the accident, I get this error:

```
The given entity of type 'Racing\Entity\Accident' (Racing\Entity\Accident@0000000072a5fbd400007f1c433b761e) has no identity/no id values set. It cannot be added to the identity map.
```

So my question: How can I create an own entity (Accident) that has RacingVehicle and Race as primary key while really having an own PHP class entity (I can create a many to many relationship, but in that case I won't have an own Accident entity).

Comment: Shouldn't `RacingVehicle` have a relation with `Race` as well? Or do I Or is it not bound to a `Race`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can add both `Driver` and `Vehicle` as ids to `RacingVehicle`. Then `Accident` would look like this:

```
<?php
namespace Racing\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Accident
{
    //...

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Racing\Entity\Driver")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="Driver_Id", referencedColumnName="Id", nullable=false)
     */
    private $Driver;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Racing\Entity\Vehicle")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="Vehicle_Id", referencedColumnName="Id", nullable=false)
     */
    private $Vehicle;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Racing\Entity\Race")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="Race_Id", referencedColumnName="Id", nullable=false)
     */
    private $Race;

    //...
}
```

It means you get a composite key of three columns. You can now use your `Driver_Id` column and `Vehicle_Id` column to resolve the `RacingVehicle` inside your accident.

Not sure if you can map it directly since it will probably result in conflicting indexes (since the index for `Driver_Id` is tied to the identifier in your `Driver` table and the index of `Vehicle_Id` to the identifier in your `Vehicle` table) But you can for example load or create a proxy to your `RacingVehicle` in a lifecycle event.

Comment: Thank you. I also ended up with that solution after trying it. The transformed entities will be loaded and a find by ID (of driver/vehicle etc.) will by applied, so that's no problem at all.